# Android Kotlin: In the override function, such as login.setOnClickListener, NullPointerException will often appear

Tags: android, kotlin

I don’t know why this happens in the overriding function. If the function is called directly, it won’t happen!I am learning Kotlin, this is the problem I encountered, I hope I can get the answer here!Please forgive my english！

---

This is BaseActivity：

```kotlin
package com.companybt.pan.base

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.companybt.pan.utils.MainApplication

/**
 * Base Actvity
 */
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle();
    }

    open fun setStyle() {
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        MainApplication.instance.removeActivity(this);
    }
}
```

---

This is LoginActivity:

```kotlin
package com.companybt.pan.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import com.companybt.pan.R
import com.companybt.pan.base.BaseActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    }

    override fun setStyle() {
        login.setOnClickListener {

        }

        register.setOnClickListener {

        }

    }
}
```

---

This will appear：

2020-06-20 22:30:10.959 20638-20638/? E/m.companybt.pa: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-06-20 22:30:11.135 20638-20743/com.companybt.pan E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@43950e
2020-06-20 22:30:11.231 20638-20638/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.companybt.pan, PID: 20638
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.companybt.pan/com.companybt.pan.activity.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3895)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.companybt.pan.activity.LoginActivity.setStyle(LoginActivity.kt:17)
at com.companybt.pan.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:15)
at com.companybt.pan.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.kt:11)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3868)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)

Comment: Your parent activity onCreate() method calling setStyle() method right? And it's is happening before you call setContentView().  So obviously you will get Null pointer.

Comment: Move setStyle() method calling to onPostCreate() on your parent activity instead of calling it in onCreate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreate()` method of `LoginActivity` class `super. onCreate()`, and therefore `setStyle()`, is called before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)`. To have access to Views such as `login` and `register` `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)` must be called first.

On of the solutions for your case is to move calling `setStyle()` method to `onResume()` method of `BaseActivity`.

Or another solution is to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)` in `setStyle()` method of `LoginActivity` before accessing the views:

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun setStyle() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        login.setOnClickListener {

        }

        register.setOnClickListener {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I want!